# Publish Python project code coverage with pytest in Azure Pipelines

Tags: python, azure-pipelines, pytest, code-coverage

I am trying to pblish code coverage results on the pipeline run summary page. This is my  pipeline.yaml file:

```
- bash: |
        pip install .[test]
        pip install pytest pytest-azurepipelines pytest-cov
        pytest --junitxml=junit.xml --cov=./src_dir --cov-report=xml --cov-report=html tests  
  displayName: Test

- task: PublishCodeCoverageResults@1
  inputs:
      codeCoverageTool: Cobertura
      summaryFileLocation: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/**/coverage.xml'
      reportDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/**/htmlcov'
```

The coverage report keeps showing 0% always

[image: screenshot-pipeline-run]

How to get the correct code coverage results?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get the correct code coverage using the following in my Azure pipeline "Test" stage:

```
        echo "
        [run]
        source = 
          $(Build.Repository.Name)" > .coveragerc
         
        coverage run --context=mytest -m pytest -v -rA --junitxml=junit.xml  --rootdir=tests
        coverage report -m --context=mytest
```

Comment: ```pip install pytest  pytest-cov &&
   pytest -v -rA --junitxml=junit.xml  --rootdir=tests --cov-report xml --cov-report html --cov=$(Build.Repository.Name) ```

This worked as well  :)